# Opening a Modal view from action-sheet button is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am working on a school project and I wanted to open a modal view from the action-sheet button but I do get this error below
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMedicationModalCtrl' of undefined` but when I use ion-button out side the action-sheet, it works.

the snapshot of the sample code below

```js
constructor(
    private addMedicationModalCtrl: ModalController,
    private actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController,

  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  addMedication() {
    console.log("add medication");
    this.addMedicationModalCtrl.create({
      component: CreateMedicationComponent
    }).then(modalEle => {
      modalEle.present();
    });
  }


  onTreatment() {
    const actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
      header: 'Treatment',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Medication',
          role: 'medication',
          handler: this.addMedication,
        },
      ],

    })
    actionSheet.then(actionSheetEle => {
      actionSheetEle.present();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please slightly change your actionsheet handler function. it will start working for you

```
onTreatment() {
    const actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
        header: 'Treatment',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Medication',
                role: 'medication',
                handler: () => {
                    this.addMedication()
                },
            },
        ],

    })
    actionSheet.then(actionSheetEle => {
        actionSheetEle.present();
    });
}
```

Comment: yes, this does the magic and thanks for helping out. But I why did not work in the first place, my code do actually called the method because I try console.log to test if the method was actually called, but it works. @TaylorRahul

Comment: its because of the fat arrow function and normal javascript function .. fat arrow function have access to the arguments object of the closest non-arrow parent function. while non fat arrow function has access to its function only... for more details please check below URL https://medium.com/better-programming/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-f65639aba256